# Динамическое изменение выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, ul

[image]
[image]
Есть поле ввода. Когда начинаю вводить какое-то слово, отправляется запрос к апи, я обрабатываю ответ и результат вывожу на страницу. Если я продолжаю вводить данные в поле, то у меня снова отправляется запрос и обработанные данные снова отображаются на странице. Но новый список из пяти пунктов появляется над старым списком, а мне нужно, чтобы новый вставал вместо старого. Подскажите, как удалять старый вывод, чтобы на его месте появлялся новый?

При обновлении данных всегда выпадающий список должен состоять из пяти пунктов

вот мой код:

```
const input = document.querySelector('.inputText');
let ul = document.querySelector('.items');
let valueFromInput;

const autocomplete = (data) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    ul.prepend(li)
    li.textContent = data.name
}

async function getData() {
    valueFromInput = this.value;
    console.log(valueFromInput)
    return await fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${valueFromInput}`)
    .then(res => {
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        return data.items.slice(-5)
    })
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element)
            autocomplete(element)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err)) 
 }
```

Comment: заведите массив с элементами и при каждом запросе очищайте его, а при получении данных заполняйте его новыми данными и выводите

Comment: @meine вот вопрос именно в том как очистить этот массив

Comment: `array = [];` **

Comment: @meine правильно понимаю, после вызова функции autocomlete мне нужно обнулять мой массив data?

Comment: обнуляйте при вызове функции getData и выполняйте запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.then(data => {
    ul.innerHTML = ''; // <--
    data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
        autocomplete(element)
    })
})
```